# How do I pass the data in a Vector as a parameter?

Tags: java, excel, swing, user-interface, jtable

I'm fairly new to java and I'm working on a project where I need to have 3 classes, the boundary, controller, and entity class. What I am trying to do is for the boundary to call the controller, which validates and in turn calls the entity class for my excel database.

I'm guessing I'll have to store the data in a Vector and pass it as parameter, which I'm currently trying to do but to no avail, the data isn't showing in my JTable. Am I taking the right approach? Or do I have to set the data to a DefaultTableModel model in my entity class first, before passing the model as my parameter? Codes are pasted below for reference.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Entity Class

```
public boolean getTable(Vector headers, Vector data)
    {

        headers = new Vector();
        data = new Vector();

        File file = new File("Triager.xls");
        try
        {
            Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
            headers.clear();
            for(int i = 0;i<sheet.getColumns();i++)
            {
                Cell cell1 = sheet.getCell(i,0);
                headers.add(cell1.getContents());
            }

            data.clear();
            for(int j = 1; j < sheet.getRows();j++)
            {
                Vector d = new Vector();
                for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getColumns();i++)
                {
                    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i,j);
                    d.add(cell.getContents());
                }
                d.add("\n");
                data.add(d);
            }
            
            found = true;

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*model = new DefaultTableModel(data,headers);
        setModel(model);
        getModel(model);*/

        return found;
    }
```

Controller Class

```
public class TCommentController 
{
    TComment tc = new TComment();
    DefaultTableModel model;

    public boolean validateTable(Vector data, Vector headers)
    {
        if(tc.getTable(data,headers))
        {
            return true;
        }

        else 
        return false;

    }

    
}
```

Boundary Class

```
class Test extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();

    public Test()
    {
  
        TCommentController c=new TCommentController();
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        Vector v1 = new Vector();
        Vector v2 = new Vector();
        boolean found;
        found = c.validateTable(v1, v2);
        if(found)
        {
            JTable table = new JTable();
            model = new DefaultTableModel(v1,v2);
            table.setModel(model);
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
            panel4.add(scroll);
        }
        
        
        Container c1 = getContentPane();
        c1.add(panel4,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        t1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t1.setSize(550,450);
        t1.setVisible(true);

        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Vectors contain no data. What you really want to do is create the Vectors in your method and add data to each Vector. Then you use the Vectors to create your TableModel and then return the TableModel. Then you use the returned TableModel to create your JTable.

Comment: Is this really a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?